# How to show a line just below the windows form title bar

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to display a line just below the Windows Form header text. Suppose my `Winform` title is `"My application"`, I want to draw a line just below the `"My application"` text of the same width as the windows form.

[image: concept illustration]

To achieve this, I am currently adding a `Label` of `height 2` and `dock top` that lets me visualize the line, but it shows up only in the client area of the windows form only. some part of the left & right windows form areas are not showing the line. (I am using `Devexpress xtraform` in `Metropolis` skin.)

How can I achieve this visual ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want a line in `ClientRectangle` or in `Caption`? not clear to me, a snapshot would be better.

Comment: @patxy wow? Devexpress label can interprete html tag?

Comment: Hi King, I dont know how to upload image here at stack overflow. But if you want to see, the image, you can go to devexpress and download attachment, I have uploaded there. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q502411

Comment: Just call e.Graphics.DrawLine(...) in the form's Paint event handler.  To what degree that's compatible with the DevExpress skinning library is hard to guess.  Do use the company's support forums to find help if you can't get DrawLine() to work.

Comment: @HansPassant I think `e.Graphics.DrawLine(...)` will draw a line in the client area only. The OP also wants to draw the line on the non - client area. If using Windows 7, I'm afraid that it needs more code. Looks like the form he uses is kind of Metro and that form may be different.

Comment: That window doesn't have a non-client area.  Note the fake caption.  Pretty typical hack for skinning libraries.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess that's a fake, but somehow they fake the `ClientRectangle` to make it look like standard window and the `Paint` can affect only on that `fake Client Area`. I tested and it is the same to the standard window, can't draw on its non-client area with custom code in `Paint` event handler. But using `GetWindowDC()` and `Graphics.FromHdc()` can get the `Graphics` of the whole window and draw it OK, which doesn't work (can't draw on the non-client area) with a Windows 7 standard form (with Aero-enabled).

Comment: Thanks everyone, Though Drawline doesn't help, I used FormPainter as suggested by Devex support, and it made a trick. 
I have also posted the solution, at the above give link.

Comment: @RohitPrakash that library allows you to draw everything  on the Caption area, but I've recognized that when you maximize the form, the line becomes very close to the control buttons `min,max,close` which looks a little ugly to me. But if you use `DrawLine` yourself (on the whole window at the appropriate coordinates), it will look better no matter the window state is maximized or not. However, it need more code :) - ah, I think you should complain about that little flaw and see if they could give you another solution?